# How does Double Hashing work?

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hash, double-hashing

I'm reading about double hashing and how it's used with the open addressing scheme for hash tables. I understand the requirement that a hash function h(k) in open addressing needs to generate a probe sequence for a given key k such that the probe sequence is some permutation of the set <0, 1, ..., m-1> for m buckets. Linear probing does this trivially by incrementing by the probe count using the function

```
h(k,i) = (h1(k) + i) mod m
```

Double hashing uses the function

```
h(k,i) = (h1(k) + i*h2(k)) mod m
```

so that the probing occurs in increments of i*h2(k).

A recommendation for double hashing is to choose 'm' as a power of two and always return an odd number from h2(k) so that these two numbers are relatively prime. How does this guarantee a probe sequence that is a permutation of the set <0, 1, ..., m-1>?

Comment: You might have better luck getting an answer on [cs.se].

Comment: Or mathoverflow.net. But here's the quickie: m is a power of two, k is odd, h, i and j are integers where j > i. Suppose `h + i*k ==(mod m) h + j*k`. Subtracting the left-hand side from both sides, we get `0 ==(mod m) (j-i)*k` which is equivalent to saying `(j-i)*k = c*m` for some `c`. Since `k` is odd and `m` is a power of 2, gcd(k,m) == 1, so if `(j-i)*k = c*m`, then `m` must be a factor of `j-i`, which means that `j - i` is at least `m`. QED.

Answer (score 3):

The probe sequence reaches all positions if and only if h2(k) and m are relatively prime. To see this, solve the equation

```
a + i * b = c     (mod m)
```

for i:

```
i = (c - a) * inv(b)    (mod m)
```

b does only have an inverse if it is relatively prime to m.

The two simple strategies to achieve this are

1. choose m to be a prime and let h2(k) return values in [1,m-1]
2. choose m to be a power of two and let h2(k) return odd numbers in [1,m-1]

Answer (score 0):

*Answer to 2nd part*

In double hashing, let the hash function be h(k, i) where k is the key and i is the probe sequence.

Let h(k, i) = h(k, j) for some i and j where j > i. This means that starting at ith step, after (j-i) more steps, the hash function points to the same slot.
Let m be the size of the table. Also, h<sub>1</sub>(k) and h<sub>2</sub>(k) are ordinary hash functions.

**h(k, i) = h(k, j)

(h<sub>1</sub>(k) + i * h<sub>2</sub>(k)) mod m = (h<sub>1</sub>(k) + j * h<sub>2</sub>(k)) mod m

(i * h<sub>2</sub>(k)) mod m = (j * h<sub>2</sub>(k)) mod m

((j - i) * h<sub>2</sub>(k)) mod m = 0**

Since, h<sub>2</sub>(k) and m are relatively prime, therefore (j - i) must be a multiple or at least m. Therefore, for the hashing function to repeat the slot, the steps must be at least m.

This proves that keeping h<sub>2</sub>(k) and m relatively prime, the double hashing hits all slot in a table of size m producing all permutations of m.

As odd numbers and power of 2s are relatively prime. Using m = 2<sup>r</sup> and h<sub>2</sub>(k) producing only odd numbers works.